# VarCorr in R is overloaded, both lme4 and nlme have versions

Tags: r

I have an lme model object generated by lme from nlme.  I also have lme4 loaded.  Now I want to extract the variance components using VarCorr().  However, both packages have a function by that name.  By default, R uses the lme4 version, which is not compatible with lme objects.  How do I tell it to use the nlme version?  Or delete the lme4 version from the search path?
Thanks.

Comment: Using detach("package:lme4") helps - but isn't there a better way to *specify* which package a function comes from?

Comment: probably `package::function()`?

Comment: R does not use the lme4 version by default. It depends on the order in which the packages are loaded. Furthermore I prefer to avoid loading nlme and lme4 at the same time.

Comment: for what it's worth, recent (post-1.0) versions of `lme4` and `nlme` play together much more nicely; there's no longer any conflict between their versions of `VarCorr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you can specify what package you want to use a function from by using package::function() notation

```
nlme::VarCorr()
```

should get you what you want.

Comment: Or the triple colon for nonexported ("internal to the package") functions.  `package:::secret_function`.

Comment: ...and (in Rgui at least) you can hit TAB TAB after :: or ::: to see the (first couple of) functions. I find that very useful!